# Application_BeginRequest not firing on IIS - don't want to use runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, global-asax, system.web

I've implemented the Application_BeginRequest method in my Global.asax.cs file for rewriting url purposes.
It works fine when running locally but when publishing it to an IIS it doesn't fire...

I found several places which recommend to use the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests flag (in the web.config) and set it to true and it indeed works with this option set. But I don't want to work with this flag set, I want to add only the required module in order for the Application_BeginRequest event to fire.

I've searched the relevant module but haven't found. Anyone knows what is the relevant module? or is there some other way?

Comment: Install IIS rewrite on server then it will work.

Comment: Already got this installed and tried to work with this static rules configuration, but it didn't work. I read over here http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html and indeed it seems that I don't load the relevant MVC modules.